# using perl, I want to replace a character in a certain position on line one only with a different value based on criteria

Tags: perl

I am a perl newbie and I need a command that will

1. read in an input file of any length
2. examine character 71 of the first line (only)
3. if the value in that position is a, change it to 1.  If it is b, change it to 2, and so on through j (10).
4. write the output to a new file

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: It would help us if you could give an example of the code you have tried so far and the problems you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution with a perl one-liner typed on the command line. Add a **-i** to the command line to edit file(s) in place or use **>** to direct to new file. Using -i or -i.old I.e. **perl -i -pe** ... you can give as many files as you want - using $ARGV to reset line one position and all of them will have line one modified appropriately.

```
tcsh 55> cat test1.in
```

```
this is test line one there is a "c" at character position 71 ........c....
this is also a test line there is a "c" at character position 71 .....c....
```

```
tcsh 56> perl -pe 'BEGIN{$a="a";$h{$a++}=++$i while ($i<10)} if ($.==1){s/^(.{70})([a-j])(.*)/sprintf("%s%d%s",$1,$h{$2},$3)/e}' test.in
```

```
this is test line one there is a "c" at character position 71 ........3....
this is also a test line there is a "c" at character position 71 .....c....
```